# Get specific value from a Nested JSON using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am totally new to Node.JS. I have written the Node.JS code and getting the response in JSON file. The JSON is in Nested Format. I want to get, store in a variable and print only one value inside the Nested JSON.

Code:

```
var https = require('https');
var optionget = {
 host : 'api-dev.dataoverflow.com',
 port : 443,
 path : '/test1/test2/MR0000091/benifits?latency=RTIME',
 method : 'GET',
 HEADERS: {
  'Authorization' : 'Basic Qjrfrfhurhfurhjfr2839gbfwj==',
  'X-PruAppID : 'PlainCardPortal'
  }
 };

console.info(optionsget)

var reqGet = htttps.request(optionsget, function(res) {
console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
res.on('data', function(d) {
process.stdout.write(d);
});
});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
console.error(e);
});

var optionsgetmsg = {
 host : 'api-dev.dataoverflow.com',
 port : 443,
 method : 'GET'
};

console.info(optionsgetmsg);

var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
res.setEncoding('utf-8')

    res.on('data', function(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data);
    });
});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
 console.error(e);
});
```

Getting the whole JSON:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "image":
        {
            "url": "images/0001.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
        },
    "thumbnail":
        {
            "url": "images/thumbnails/0001.jpg",
            "width": 32,
            "height": 32
        }
}
```

I want to get the `width=32` only which is under thumbnail. I want to store it in a variable and want to print in console.

Comment: `htttps.request` Is this normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse()` in order to convert your JSON string into an object, and then you can retrieve your value as you would a regular JS object like this:

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
process.stdout.write(console.log(parsedData.image.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
res.on('data', (d) => {
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(d);
  console.log('width = ', jsonObj.thumbnail.width);
});
```

JSON.parse() will transform the received string in `d` to a JavaScript object. You then can access the object via standard dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string using JSON.parse(...). The object is then a standard JavaScript object.  You can access it using either dot notation (e.g. object.property) or via index notation (e.g. object['property'])

You can also nest those, such as in your example, data.thumbnail.width

```
res.on('data', (d) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(d);
    let width = data.thumbnail.width;
    console.log(width);
});
```

However, if thumbnail could possibly be undefined, you should check for that.

```
res.on('data', (d) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(d);
    let width = undefined;
    if (data.thumbnail) width = data.thumbnail.width;
    console.log(width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'api-dev.dataoverflow.com:443/test1/test2/MR0000091/benifits?latency=RTIME',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic Qjrfrfhurhfurhjfr2839gbfwj==',
        'X-PruAppID': 'PlainCardPortal'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```